# Invalid syntax error with apostrophe

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I must be really off my game today because I'm getting a syntax error with a pretty simple task.

```
def hours_and_minutes_str(hours, minutes):
    """returns a string that represents the time span, including units

    number, number -> str"""
    return str(hours ' hours'  , minutes , " minutes")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please note that the docstring and signature messed up the format of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing a comma

```
return str(hours, ' hours'  , minutes , " minutes")
```